# I need to browse record with variable value

Tags: python, python-2.7, odoo

Here is the code:

```
variable=field_name
send_address_purchase=res_brw.variable  (so i need res_brw.field_name)
```

How could i dynamically access field by variable value?

Comment: Please fix your code formatting

Comment: access the field of what?

Comment: Solved it by using eval function

Comment: send_address_purchase=eval('res_brw.'+variable)

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `eval`, use `getattr` instead:

```
variable = field_name
send_address_purchase = getattr(res_brw, variable)
```

Comment: Ohh yes Thank you. This would be better and secure.